# UUID not getting auto generated in Spring JPA Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, azure-sql-database, uuid

This is my Model defination:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "decileconfig")
public class DecileConfig extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    @NotNull(groups = DecileConfig.Existing.class)
    @Null(groups = DecileConfig.New.class)
    @Column(name="id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = false)
    private String id; // This has to be String
..
```

This is my table:

```
create table Allocationtest.global_configuration
  (
      id varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY key,
```

When I am trying to insert data I am getting this:

```
**org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement**
```

I think somehow auto-generation of ID column is not happening.

Update:
After changing to this as follows:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    @NotNull(groups = DecileConfig.Existing.class)
    @Null(groups = DecileConfig.New.class)
    @Column(name="id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = false)
    private String id;
```

I am getting this :

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [2b221537-1089-4ab3-ae81-c8fbf44bb293] value by reflection : [class com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.service.model.DecileConfig.id] setter of com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.service.model.DecileConfig.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [2b221537-1089-4ab3-ae81-c8fbf44bb293] value by reflection : [class com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.service.model.DecileConfig.id] setter of com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.service.model.DecileConfig.id

Comment: Why are you using a String and not a UUID as type of the ID. And why do you want to store it in a VARCHAR?

Comment: Thats a requirement you can say. I tried with UUID which is working fine. But I need specifically String.

Comment: Then you can't use the generator. But you can just assign a UUID as the default value.

Comment: Let me try removing generator.

Comment: Now I am getting this :ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.service.model.DecileConfig after removing @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize the object from say a REST api? Validate your JSON->Java object conversion has the ID set on post operations - and you might want to disallow it being set and auto assign it yourself to ensure users don't have control over ID generation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the UUID as the default value:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "decileconfig")
public class DecileConfig extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @NotNull(groups = DecileConfig.Existing.class)
    @Null(groups = DecileConfig.New.class)
    @Column(name="id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = false)
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: Getting this exception : ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.service.model.DecileConfig tried as you shown in your answer

Comment: Is that expected?

Comment: I tried it in a sample Project and it works fine

Comment: Is it generating id automatically without explicit input?

Comment: Please checkout https://github.com/simasch-scratches/jpa-uuid

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error and this fixed my issue:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;
```

Had to change from String to UUID